Linux Kernel hash table iteration gives NULL pointer
I'm writing a kernel object that should keep a set of threads information and access them by tid.
For this purpose I'm using the hashtable data structure. Every time I get a thread info, I should check if its tid is already in the table - and reset a counter, otherwise add a new structure. To check if the tid is already present, I use the hash_for_each macro in this way:
struct thread_check {
    unsigned short  cnt;
    unsigned short  maxcnt;
    int tid;
    char functionname[32];
    char alm;
    struct hlist_node node;
};

static int __init module_init(void) {
    DECLARE_HASHTABLE(nodes_hash, 3);
    hash_init(nodes_hash);
}

function refresh(char procfs_buffer[1024]) {
    token = procfs_buffer;  // in the form s|1234|functionName
    strsep(&token, "|");    // skip first token - the s character
    res = kstrtol(strsep(&token, "|"), 10, &tid);
    found = false;
    hash_for_each(nodes_hash, bkt, cur, node) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "sono a %d\n", __LINE__);
        if (cur != NULL && cur->tid == tid) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "sono a %d\n", __LINE__);
            cur->cnt = 0;
            printk(KERN_INFO "sono a %d\n", __LINE__);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "sono a %d\n", __LINE__);
    }
    if (!found) {
        t = (struct thread_check *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct thread_check), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->tid = tid;
            t->cnt = 0;
            t->maxcnt = 0;
            t->node.next = 0;
            t->node.pprev = 0;
            memset(t->functionname, 0, 32);
            strncpy(t->functionname, token, strlen(token));
            hash_add(nodes_hash, &t->node, t->tid);
        }
    }
}

In some cases, inside the for-each macro, I get a
BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
in the dmesg, and a thread dies. Any suggestion? I was considering change the macro with hash_for_each_safe or hash_for_each_possible, but I don't know the difference between these variants.

How long is a token string? Assuming sizeof(t->functionname) is 32, the call strncpy(t->functionname, token, strlen(token)); will overrun t->functionname if strlen(token) is greater than 32, and t->functioname will not be null terminated in strlen(token) is greater than 31.

Could another CPU be modifying the hash table while you are searching or inserting?

Thank you for your answers. About the second point: no. there is no other cpu editing the hash table. About the first, the function name is extract splitting a string in the format tid|functionname. Currently, function name is 15 chars long as maximum

Instead of hash_for_each, which iterates over the whole table, use hash_for_each_possible, which iterates only over the bucket, where nodes with a specific key (in your case - thread id) could reside. This is the whole purpose of the has table to limit a search to a specific bucket.

As for the crash you got, it is probably related with your other code, which is absent in the question post. Please, read what [mcve] is.

I edited the question adding more code. That should be all what involves the hash table

The macro DECLARE_HASHTABLE defines the variable to be the hash table. Because you use that macro inside module_init, that hash table (and the variable) exists only inside that function. Smells like you have not initialized the hash table for your global nodes_hash variable.

@Tsyvarev So the code may initializing the wrong hash table variable.

@Tsyvarev A global static DECLARE_HASHTABLE(nodes_hash, 3); would be initialized implicitly (as it is just an array of struct hlist_head which consists of a single pointer member whose initial value should be NULL), although it may be good practice to initialize it explicitly, as is required when allocated dynamically.
